# Can I flag multiple reasons in the 10k tools?

Tags: discussion, review, flags, 10k-tools

I'm finding it quite common to see the following situation in the 10k flag review queue:

- An answer has been flagged as NAA by several users
- The answer *is* actually an attempt at an answer but it's poor quality

So, I feel like I have to take the option saying that the post has invalid flags, and yet I can't subsequently flag the answer again as poor quality.

Does it matter?
Am I doing the right thing?
Should I just flag it as poor quality and leave the NAA flags undisputed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the answer is worthy of a VLQ flag, I would add that flag rather than disputing the others. It's more helpful (I think) to ensure correct flags are attached to the answer than to dispute ones that are well intentioned but semantically wrong. After all, if it's worthy of a VLQ flag then we need it deleted.