# Allow user to select multiple concurrent flag reasons

Tags: feature-request, flags

When you flag an answer, a popup come sup with a set of radio buttons that allow you to select a reason for the flag. One answer that i just ran in to was both rude and of very low quality. I think it would have been better to have checkboxes by the reasons instead of radio buttons. In the end, I chose the last option "needs moderator attention" so that I could state both reasons for the flag (incorrect use of that option?).

This request is different from [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176910/224263) in that as a single user I would like to add multiple flags at one time before y previous flag has been looked at. This request is also different from [this other meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216510/224263) as the flags would be assigned from a user's perspective not during a review session.

In summary:

1. is it possible to have checkboxes or some other mechanism to allow a user to flag a question/answer/comment for multiple reasons at the same time?
2. Is there a site-philosophical or implementation reason why this cannot happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that should be necessary.  If a question is a bad apple for multiple reasons, any one of them will do - the action is the same, generally (deleting), and if there is a bigger issue (like rudeness), choose that flag as it seems more important to have the poster told not to be rude than just to delete a VLQ question.

Further, if you're wrong about one reason but would be right about another, odds are the moderator will take the correct action anyway; these aren't like close votes in that they automatically disappear without a person seeing them and acting on them.

Comment: @Joe I feel like specifying all the reasons an entity should be deleted would build the strongest case possible to the moderators who may only view the post in light of the one specified reason or may be on the fence about taking action. Would there be any harm in allowing multiple reasons?

Comment: One flag isn't going to make much of a difference to a moderator's opinion.  A dozen users flagging the same post, sure, and then if you really had a post with two potential reasons, you'd see a mixture of reasons given - that's very common from what I see on the 10k user tools (6 votes for VLQ, 5 for NAA for example).  In terms of what harm, the harm is that it a) makes the UI more complicated without adding value, and b) means you don't have to make the choice of which it truly is - you could just flag a post and put all reasons as checked and hope the mod agreed with one of them.

Comment: @Joe good points about how many users will likely select various reasons, and how multi-select could be abused. Accepted.

Comment: @StevenMagana-Zook - Also, this is exactly what "other" flags are great for: they let you provide extra detail about the things that are wrong with a given post. The standard flag reasons are really there for things that at a glance only fall into one category.